# SQL Query WHERE CONTAINS syntax with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got an SQL query with multiple conditions, including a WHERE CONTAINS clause. I tried the query without that clause and it works fine. I have full text indexing on and have used the exact same WHERE CONTAINS syntax on a similar query and it works, but that query didn't have any other conditions.

```
SELECT *
FROM waitList
WHERE CONTAINS (Huts, '%'+ @huts + '%')
    AND StartDate <= @date
    AND EndDate >= @date
    AND Spaces <= @numSpaces
```

Comment: in sql server the only unit smaller than a word that can be searched is a prefix(words start with that unit)

Comment: What error are you getting with this query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The OP originally had `mysql` and `sql-server` as tags, yet they were for some reason both edited out.

Comment: @TabAlleman Removing the tags seems to have made it unclear what DBMS the OP is using.

Comment: @TotZam It was already unclear.   OP tagged two different DBMS tags, which is ambiguous.  I think that removing both and replacing with the generic SQL tag not only makes the tags more correct, but gives the OP an incentive to come back and tag his question correctly.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, not sure how I accidentally tagged both MySQL and SQL. This is for a Microsoft SQL server, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a string match, try using LIKE (or ILIKE):

```
SELECT *
FROM waitList
WHERE Huts LIKE '%'+ @huts + '%'
  AND StartDate <= @date AND EndDate >= @date
  AND Spaces <= @numSpaces
```

The code assumes you're applying the variables to a string which is then executed against your database.